# On aws able to access yourdomain.com but not able to access http://www.yourdomain.com.?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-hosting, amazon-route53, cloud-hosting

I have done the configuration on AWS I'm able to access yourdomain.com(For example) but not able to access http://www.yourdomain.com?

I'm using Amazon EC2 virtual server cloud and route 53 hosted zones.

Comment: Did you configure a "www" CNAME in your DNS? Did you configure an SSL certificate for "https"? Your question lacks all needed details, and doesn't even specify what service you are using on AWS to host your website.

Comment: I have updated the question and I have not configured a "www" CNAME in my DNS. can you provide me a example of this..?

Comment: I have configure a "www" CNAME in my DNS  like
Name-www.yourdomain.com Type-CNAME Value-yourdomain.com.

Is it correct..?

Comment: thank you very much, your provided hit worked.

Answer (score 2):

As Mark B said, your question lacks a lot of the necessary details, however I will answer based on a few assumptions.

1) I'm assuming that your instance is publicly accessible
2) I'm assuming that your instance is not inside a VPC
3) I'm assuming that your instance is not behind a load balancer

First, go to your EC2 instance and copy the public DNS of your instance. IP's can change over time, therefore best practice is to use the public DNS as the value.

Next go to Route 53, and go to the Hosted Zone for your domain and click the blue button that says "Create Record Set".

In the name field put: www
In the type, select: CNAME
In the value field you'll paste the DNS for the EC2 instance

Click create.

If you've done this right, and your security groups are correctly configured, you should be able to now visit your site using www.yourdomain.com.

Comment: Thank very much hephalump, It worked for me. I'm very new to AWS.

Comment: Glad it helped Raj. Since it worked for you I would be grateful if you would accept this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me.
Name-www.yourdomain.com Type-CNAME Value-yourdomain.com. (Dot is important)